# Plotting subsetted data in R Shiny with DateRangeInput

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to subset a data set using a few input parameters and then plot the output. I am able to plot various stats over time for various teams, but I am unable to figure out how to subset my data for an input date range. Attached is my server and ui.

Server:

```
library(shiny)

season = read.csv("2016_Season.csv")
season$date = as.POSIXct(season$date)

function(input, output) {

   adjust <- function() {

     data = season

     #data = data[data$date >= input$dates[1],]
     #data = data[data$date <= input$dates[2],]

     if (input$Team != "All"){                
      data <- data[data$Team == input$Team,] 
     }

     data = data[,c('date',input$Stat)]

      }

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

     plot(adjust())
   })
}
```

UI:

```
library(shiny)

season = read.csv("2016_Season.csv")
season$date = as.POSIXct(season$date)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Time Plot"),

  sidebarPanel(

    fluidRow(
      div(class="span4",
          selectInput('Team',
                      'Team:',
                      c('All',unique(as.character(season$Team)))))
     ),

    fluidRow(
      div(class="span4",                                            
          selectInput("Stat",                                      
                      "Stat:",
                      c('PTS','TRB','AST')))
     ),

    dateRangeInput("dates", 
                   "Date range",
                   start = min(season$date),
                   end = max(season$date))
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot")                     
  )                                           
))
```

The code works fine when the these two lines are commented out in the server, though obviously the date filters dont work:

```
 #data = data[data$date >= input$dates[1],]
 #data = data[data$date <= input$dates[2],]
```

but I remove the comments i get the error 'need finite 'xlim' values' and I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Try transforming you POSIXct to Date : `data = data[as.Date(data$date) >= input$dates[1],] `

Comment: Hey thanks that did it. Much appreciated

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you Daniel & HubertL.